# jQuery. Как обратиться к элементу массива по классу и достать CSS свойство?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Дан объект data, в нём хранятся несколько `div` с классами "`img` `img[i]`", где i изменяется от 1 до 9. Мне нужно вытащить из `div` (допустим, класса `img3`) `css` свойство `top`. Как это сделать, можете помочь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log($('.img3').css('top'));
```

```css
.img3 { top: 20% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img3"></div>
```

В вашем случае `$('.img'+i).css('top')`